# How to handle a JSON request that doesn't return JSON?

Tags: jquery, json, syntax-error

In the good case my JSON endpoint will return a proper JSON response: `{status: "success"}`. However if my webserver 500 errors the 500 response body is HTML, which results in a SyntaxError if jQuery tries to parse it with `$.parseJSON`.

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2756344/how-do-i-handle-a-json-request-returning-a-string-in-jquery?rq=1) suggests just removing the dataType param from the request.  I would rather not do that, is there a way to try/catch the SyntaxError thats raised by a non-JSON response?

Comment: can you put in your $.ajax call code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[From jQuery API](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/)

```
Important: As of jQuery 1.4, if the JSON file contains a syntax error, 
the request will usually fail silently.
```

You can handle it the error callback.

```
$.ajax({
        url: "MYURL",
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(data) {

        },
        error: function(e) {
          if(e.status == 500)
            alert("500 Internal Server Error");
        }
});
```